# Compute $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\cos(2 \pi n x)}{n}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I wanted to confirm that my computation of this series and the result are correct. I could not find the answer anywhere.

Consider

$$\begin{align}S&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\cos(2 \pi n x)}{n}\\ 
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}e^{2 \pi i n x}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}e^{-2 \pi i n x}\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \left[ \log(1+e^{2 \pi i  x})+ \log(1+e^{-2 \pi i  x}) \right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \left[ \log(1+e^{2 \pi i  x})(1+e^{-2 \pi i  x}) \right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \left[ \log(2+e^{2 \pi i  x}+e^{-2 \pi i  x}) \right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \left[ \log(2+2 \cos(2 \pi x))\right]\end{align}$$

Recalling the double angle formula for $\cos(2A)$

$$\boxed{\cos(2A)=1-2 \sin^2(A)}$$

we get

$$S=\frac{1}{2} \left[ \log(2+2 (1-2\sin^2( \pi x)) \right]$$

$$S=\frac{1}{2} \left[ \log(4 -4\sin^2( \pi x)) \right]$$

$$S=\frac{1}{2} \left[ \log(4 (1-\sin^2( \pi x))) \right]$$

$$S=\frac{1}{2} \left[ \log(4 \cos^2( \pi x)) \right]$$

$$S=\frac{1}{2} \left[ \log(4)+ \log( \cos^2( \pi x)) \right]$$

$$\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\cos(2 \pi n x)= \log(2)+ \log( \cos( \pi x)) }$$

Comment: Not sure if it is correct, but surely if your reasoning is correct, it should be $\log 2+\log|\cos x|$

Comment: If you chose the formula $\cos 2A=2\cos^2A-1,$ you could have greatly simplified your argument.

Comment: For complex values, we don’t always have $\log z +\log w=\log(zw) $ But when $zw$ is real and positive, it is true.